# ReactJS FixedDataTable sorting and filtering example not working

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I am trying to follow this ReactJS tutorial :

Part 1 : http://4dev.tech/2015/12/reactjs-datatable-with-sort-filter-and-pagination-example-part-1/

Part 2 : http://4dev.tech/2016/03/tutorial-sorting-and-filtering-a-reactjs-datatable/

I finished part 1 successfully and I need some help to finish part 2.

This is my code for part 2 :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';

class MyTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.rows = [{"id":1,"first_name":"William","last_name":"Elliott","email":"welliott0@wisc.edu",
             "country":"Argentina","ip_address":"247.180.226.89"},
              {"id":2,"first_name":"Carl","last_name":"Ross","email":"cross1@mlb.com",
             "country":"South Africa","ip_address":"27.146.70.36"},
              {"id":3,"first_name":"Jeremy","last_name":"Scott","email":"jscott2@cbsnews.com",
             "country":"Colombia","ip_address":"103.52.74.225"},
             ]
    this.state = {
      filteredDataList: this.rows
    };
  }

_renderHeader(label, cellDataKey) {
  return <div>
        <span>{label}</span>
          <div>
            <br />
            <input style={{width:90+'%'}} onChange={this._onFilterChange.bind(this, cellDataKey)}/>
          </div>
      </div>;
}

_onFilterChange(cellDataKey, event) {
  if (!event.target.value) {
    this.setState({
      filteredDataList: this.rows,
    });
  }
  var filterBy = event.target.value.toString().toLowerCase();
  var size = this.rows.length;
  var filteredList = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    var v = this.rows[index][cellDataKey];
    if (v.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
      filteredList.push(this.rows[index]);
    }
  }
  this.setState({
    filteredDataList: filteredList,
  });
}

  render() {
      return <Table
        height={40+((this.rows.length+1) * 30)}
        width={1150}
        rowsCount={this.rows.length}
        rowHeight={30}
        headerHeight={30}
        rowGetter={function(rowIndex) {return this.rows[rowIndex]; }.bind(this)}>
        <Column dataKey="id" width={50} label="Id"
            headerRenderer={this._renderHeader.bind(this)}/>
        <Column dataKey="first_name" width={200} label="First Name" />
        <Column  dataKey="last_name" width={200} label="Last Name" />
        <Column  dataKey="email" width={400} label="e-mail" />
        <Column  dataKey="country" width={300} label="Country" />
      </Table>;
  }
}

module.exports = MyTable;
```

The datatable is showing but not the input fields which are used to filter the rows.

The browser console is not showing any errors except few warnings :

```
`rowGetter` will be DEPRECATED in version 0.7.0 of FixedDataTable and beyond. 
Please use the cell API in Column to fetch data for your cells.
Read the docs at: https://fburl.com/FixedDataTable-v0.6
`label` will be DEPRECATED in version 0.7.0 of FixedDataTable and beyond. 
Please use `header` instead.
Read the docs at: https://fburl.com/FixedDataTable-v0.6
`dataKey` will be DEPRECATED in version 0.7.0 of FixedDataTable and beyond. 
Please use the `cell` API to pass in a dataKey
Read the docs at: https://fburl.com/FixedDataTable-v0.6
`headerRenderer` will be DEPRECATED in version 0.7.0 of FixedDataTable and beyond. 
Please use the `header` API to pass in a React Element instead.
Read the docs at: https://fburl.com/FixedDataTable-v0.6
```

I have no clue what the problem is.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

While this question is a year old, I ran into similar trouble recently and can share my experience.  Also, I don't know what your level of React familiarity is, but I'll try to explain in a beginner friendly manner to help others out, so bear with me if anything seems obvious.

So, the browser error you're getting is due to the API change as alluded to in another answer.  The tutorial you are referencing is using the old API.  The new API changes involve a few things.  Namely, you no longer have access to `rowGetter`, `headerDataGetter`, `headerRenderer`, `dataKey`, and `label` , among other things.

The new API involves providing data directly into the cell components, which I'll demonstrate.

So first of all, you can make custom cells now, so you can set them up to have the behaviors that you want.  We'll be creating a text cell class `MyTextCell` to display text within the grid, and a header cell class `SortHeaderCell` that we can click on to sort the column, and display an arrow showing the sort order.  You can add a custom cell class for your email column as well, to make the email addresses links.

I'll cover sorting first, since I thought it was more difficult.  This basically uses the same methodology as the examples in the docs.

Now the data you have now is just an array, which is fine.  The docs use a DataListWrapper class, however, which has a `_data` property that contains your data, and another `_indexMap` property for sort indexes, so let's make that (note if you're looking at the examples in the docs, I changed this a little bit):

```
class DataListWrapper {
  constructor(indexMap, data) {
      this._indexMap = indexMap;
      this._data = data;
  }

  getSize() {
      return this._indexMap.length;
  }

  getObjectAt(index) {
      let sortedIdx = this._indexMap[index];
      return this._data[sortedIdx];
  }
}
```

You can make the custom cell types mentioned earlier as stateless components like our custom text cell:

```
 const MyTextCell = ({ rowIndex, field, data, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Cell {...props}>
            {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[field]}
        </Cell>
    );
 }
```

Or, you can make them stateful like in this custom sort header cell.  There's no reason to have one of each, I just wanted to demonstrate both options:

```
    class SortHeaderCell extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._onSortChange = this._onSortChange.bind(this);
     }
    render() {
       
        let {onSortChange, sortDir, children, ...props } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
          <Cell {...props}>
              <a onClick={this._onSortChange}>
                  {children} {sortDir ? (sortDir === SortTypes.DESC ? '↓' : '↑') : ''}
            </a>
        </Cell>
    );
}
_onSortChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.onSortChange) {
        this.props.onSortChange(
            this.props.columnKey,
            this.props.sortDir ?
                reverseSortDirection(this.props.sortDir) :
                SortTypes.DESC
        );
    }
 }
}
```

You'll also need to create your sort types:

```
 const SortTypes = {
      ASC: 'ASC',
      DESC: 'DESC',
 };
```

And a quick method to reverse sort types:

```
  function reverseSortDirection(sortDir) {
      return sortDir === SortTypes.DESC ? SortTypes.ASC : SortTypes.DESC;
  }
```

One thing to note -- we have an `_onSortChange` method here in the header, to display the arrow and call the method that actually sorts the data, but that one is going to be in the actual table component.

In your table, you'll need a few things.

In your case, your table data is hardcoded, but best practice would be to pass it in through props. Assuming you get your data through properties, you'll want to setState accordingly and also set up your default sort indexes (basically the way the data will initially be sorted).

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this._defaultSortIndexes = [];
    var size = props.myDataArray.length;
    for (var index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        this._defaultSortIndexes.push(index);
    }
    this.setState({ myTableData: props.myDataArray, sortedFilteredDataList: new DataListWrapper(this._defaultSortIndexes, props.myDataArray) }) 
}
```

So, now your headers know how to display arrows and how to call the `_onSortChange` method of the table itself.  Your table component also knows how to receive an array of data via props, and put it into a DataWrapper, and add it to state.  So we  have to make that `_onSortChange` method in the table, which will actually set the sortIndexes in the data wrapper to the correct order:

```
_onSortChange(columnKey, sortDir) {
    var sortIndexes = this._defaultSortIndexes.slice();
    sortIndexes.sort((indexA, indexB) => {
        var valueA = this.state.myTableData[indexA][columnKey];
        var valueB = this.state.myTableData[indexB][columnKey];
        var sortVal = 0;
        if (valueA > valueB) {
            sortVal = 1;
        }
        if (valueA < valueB) {
            sortVal = -1;
        }
        if (sortVal !== 0 && sortDir === SortTypes.ASC) {
            sortVal = sortVal * -1;
        }
        return sortVal;

    });

    this.setState({
        sortedFilteredDataList: new DataListWrapper(sortIndexes, this.state.myTableData),
        colSortDirs: {
            [columnKey]: sortDir,
        },
    });
}
```

So now, you can set your columns up like this:

```
     <Column
            columnKey='country'
            header={
                <SortHeaderCell
                    onSortChange={this._onSortChange}
                    sortDir={colSortDirs.country}>
                    Country
                </SortHeaderCell>}
                cell={
                    <MyTextCell
                        data={this.state.sortedFilteredDataList}
                        field="country"
                     />
                }
                width={150}
       />
```

That's pretty much it for sorting.  The docs demonstrate filtering a similar way, using a DataListWrapper with filter indexes.  I didn't do that, and just filtered my data array in the component in which my table component is nested.  Essentially, I have a component responsible for passing data to the table component via props, and filter in there.  I do it like this:

In the parent component, I have a filter/search method:

```
filterSearch(searchTerm) {
    
    this.setState({
        filteredData: this.state.myData.filter(function (el) {
            return (el.propertyToFilter.includes(searchTerm) || !searchTerm);
        })
    });
}
```

Then I render my search component and my table component:

```
        <div>
            <div>
                <SearchBox onSearchTermChange={this.filterSearch} />
            </div>

            <br />
            <div className="row">
                <div>
                    <ResultsTable myDataArray={this.state.filteredData} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My search box component is this:

```
class SearchBox extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    
    this.state= {term: ''};
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input 
     value={this.state.term}
     onChange={(e)=>this.onInputChange(e.target.value)}></input>
   
    </div>
    )
}

onInputChange(term){
    this.setState({term});
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(term);
}
}
export default SearchBox;
```

That's pretty much it.  You should also note, fixed-data-table is unsupported now, and you should use fixed-data-table-2.  That said, I did all of the above in fixed-data-table and it should work.

For documentation, the official docs are [here](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/)

Those link the the old examples though, which have some bugs.  New examples are [here](https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2/tree/b4394d1b526a5a53888abe9c2dcac1c0b57e92d0/examples)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about your fixed data table version. Please check this v0.6 API Migration at here: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/v6-migration.html

Comment: Please note: websites can go down; links can break. And tehn your answer turns useless. Thus: avoid link-only answers, and give at least some level of detail.